# How to read a value from an Attribute in XML Tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to read the value **“enquiry”** from the attribute **“name”** in the xml snippet provided below using xslt. Can anyone help me with it? I am totally new to xslt.

Thanks in advance. :)

```
<?table name="enquiry"?>
<thead>
<row rowsep="1">
<entry colname="col1">
```

Comment: Now then....Is that really your XML sample? It is not actually well-formed (i.e no closing tags), and more imporantly the **table** node is a processing-instruction! Do you really mean to have the question marks there? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC - Good point about the pi most likely being a mistake. I should've noticed that before I posted an answer.

Comment: @TimC, Actually, I have taken only a small part of the code. yes, it has an end tag and the question marks are also required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general approach would be to define a template like this:

```
  <xsl:template name="GetPIAttribute">
    <xsl:param name="pi" />
    <xsl:param name="attrName" />

    <xsl:variable name="toFind" select="concat(' ', $attrName, '=')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="piAdjusted" select="concat(' ', normalize-space($pi))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="foundMatch" select="substring-after($piAdjusted, $toFind)" />
    <xsl:if test="$foundMatch">
      <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="substring($foundMatch, 1, 1)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($foundMatch, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then you could call it to retrieve any pseudo-attribute you wanted, like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="GetPIAttribute">
      <xsl:with-param name="pi" select="/processing-instruction()[name() = 'table']" />
      <xsl:with-param name="attrName" select="'name'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

The benefit with this approach is that it accounts for the value being enclosed in either single or double quotes, and that you can reuse it if you need to extract multiple values.

Comment: This won't work when you need the id "attribute" of a PI like `<?myPI grid="wide" id="a123"?>`; 'wide' would be returned. The select attribute of the foundMatch variable should therefore be `substring-after(concat(' ', normalize-space($pi)), concat(' ', $attrName, '=')`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually an attribute. That's just the value of a processing instruction.

I think the only way to get the value is through some string manipulation...

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name()='table']">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'name=&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The processing instruction in the xml file is being skipped during the transformation. Is there any way to make this readable?